# str.reverse function reversing every array in global scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-chrome, reverse

Can't tell if my browser console is bugged, or what is going on, as I've never had issues using the reverse function.

When I throw the following into my chrome console,

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var reversed = a.reverse(); 

console.log(a);        // ['one', 'two', 'three']
console.log(reversed); // ['three', 'two', 'one']
```

I get
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array#reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) works in place and doesn't create a new array. The line

```
var reversed = a.reverse();
```

reverses `a` and also sets `reversed` to reference the same array.

In this example you can see that adding an item to `reversed` also affects `a` because they reference the same array:

```js
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var reversed = a.reverse(); 

reversed.push(1000); // add something to reversed

console.log(a);        // ['three', 'two', 'one', 1000]
console.log(reversed); // ['three', 'two', 'one', 1000]
```

To create a new array use [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on the original, and then reverse the array:

```js
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var reversed = a.slice().reverse(); 

console.log(a);        // ['one', 'two', 'three']
console.log(reversed); // ['three', 'two', 'one']
```

Comment: How would one go about setting a variable to the reversed string whilst keeping the original, so they can be compared, and log the desired output as commented?

Comment: @BrodyMacfarlane - slice and then reverse. I've added an example.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot.  Lame error on my part.  Will accept answer in just a few!

Answer (score 0):

The reverse function mutates the current array. After you declare `reversed` to be `a.reverse()`, the array `a` will be mutated as well. Thus, you will print out `['three', 'two', 'one']` for `console.log(a)` and `console.log(reversed)`

What you want to do is to make a clone of a:

`var a = ['one', 'two', 'three']; 
 var reversed = a.slice().reverse();`

`console.log(a);        // ['one', 'two', 'three']
 console.log(reversed); // ['three', 'two', 'one']`